# Slider Bootstrap JQuery Unresponsive Images

Tags: image, responsive-design, resize, slider

I've built a slider with 4 images using Bootstrap & jQuery, but I can't work out why my images will not resize (as they should automatically, as it is supposed to be responsive).

Any help much appreciated!

```
  <style>
      body, html {
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
    }
      .banner {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: auto;
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
      }
      .banner ul {
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
      }
      .banner li {
          list-style: none;
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
      }
      .banner ul li {
          float: left;
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
          min-height: 450px;
          background-size: 100% auto;
      }
  </style>
```

```
 <div class="banner">
     <ul>
         <li style="background-image: url('images/Petra 1.jpg');">
         </li>
         <li style="background-image: url('images/Petra 2.jpg');">
         </li>
         <li style="background-image: url('images/Petra 3.jpg');">
         </li>
         <li style="background-image: url('images/Petra 4.jpg');">
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.banner').unslider({
            speed: 600,   //Speed in milliseconds
            delay: 3000, // To delay between slide (in milliseconds
            keys: true,
            fluid: true,
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The images are loaded as background, and thus not resized according to the container. To resize the background you can use: `background-size:cover`, see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size